# Regular Expression to Validate Monaco Number Plates

Tags: regex

I would like to have an expression to validate the plates of monaco.
They are written as follows:

- A123
- 123A
- 1234

I started by doing:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}?[0-9]{2}?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$
```

But the case A12A which is false is possible with that.

Comment: Try `^(?!(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{4}$`

Comment: I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71951416/3832970) with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the pattern using 3 alternatives specifying all the allowed variations for the example data:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{4})$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SSBEV8/1).

Note that you can omit `{1}` and

To not match 2 chars A-Z you can write the alternation as:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]\d{3}|\d{3}[a-zA-Z\d]|\d[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d]\d)$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YgIcEK/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?!(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5srnqo/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]){2})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are two occurrences of any zero or more digits followed with two ASCII letters immediately to the right of the current location
- `[a-zA-Z\d]{4}` - four alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

So it needs 3 connected digits and 1 letter or digit.

Then you can use this pattern :

```
^(?=.?[0-9]{3})[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$
```

The lookahead `(?=.?[0-9]{3})` asserts the 3 connected digits.

Test on Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/fhTSiV/1)